# Connecting to instance using putty

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I launched a spot instance using this official cloud formation template provided by AWS labs.

https://github.com/awslabs/ec2-spot-labs/blob/master/ec2-spot-fleet-launch-templates/ec2-spot-fleet-launch-templates.yaml

I can see the instance is created but not able to connect it using putty.
Does it mean the template creates route tables without internet access?

Answer (score 0):

In the template, I can see internet gateway is attached. Can you please check security group if port 22 is allowed from `0.0.0.0` or `your IP`.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. After adding 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all traffic I was able to connect. (Just testing - no security concerns). But how do I add this statement to the template? The purpose of using cloudformation is to automate end to end process.

Comment: You have to update the script with the security group which allows right IP address for port 22. Do not allow port 22 from 0.0.0.0 it's highly unsecured